# CSS 3D Transform Only Half Clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a flippable card that flips on click. The card is default face down, and for some reason, only the right half of the card is clickable. I'm trying to make the whole card able to click and flip. JSFiddle below for example.

http://jsfiddle.net/aa3Lc/

```
.card {
    background: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 800;
    line-height: 2em;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 5px 0 ;
    text-align: center;
    width: 38px;

    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(180deg);
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.card.active {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg);
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg);
}
.card .card-front {
    display: block;
    width: 38px;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.card .card-back {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    width: 38px;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: the left half is clickable for me (firefox 27.0.1)

Comment: Same here. This appears to be a webkit bug, I think.

Comment: yeah i thnink its a webkit thing...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aa3Lc/1/ o.O

Comment: Looks like a webkit thing! I thought that I tested it in Firefox and got the same thing, but it looks like you're right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `-webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(180deg);` in `.card` to

```
-webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(180deg) translateZ(-1px);
```

to fix your issue. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aa3Lc/3/)

Not 100% sure why you have `perspective(1000px)` for each one as well... I'd put `perspective: 1000px;` below the transform on `.card` and remove all the rest

Comment: I'm not sure why I have it, either. It wasn't there originally, but I was messing around trying to get it to work, and it didn't seem to hurt.